# tree view selected node always return null

Tags: asp.net

I use the code below to add a new category to the categories table in my dataBase
but the return value of selectedNode is always null.
What is the problem?

```
protected void btnAddNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedNodeValue = CategoryTreeView.SelectedNode.Value;
     using (mydbEntities context = new mydbEntities())
        {
            int id = Int32.Parse(selectedNodeValue);
            Category obj = new Category();
            obj.Name = "bla bla";
            obj.CategoryParentId_FK = id;
            context.Categories.AddObject(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    bindTreeView();
}
```

One more thing, my categorytreeview is in update panel

this is my markup

```
<div id="MyTreeDiv" class="TreeContiner">
                <asp:TreeView ID="CategoryTreeView" runat="server" ShowLines="true" 
                    LineImagesFolder="images/treeRTLlines" CssClass="AspNet-TreeView" 
                    onselectednodechanged="CategoryTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged">
                <NodeStyle CssClass="AspNet-TreeView-Nodes" />
                <SelectedNodeStyle  CssClass="AspNet-TreeView-Selected-Nodes" />
                </asp:TreeView>
                <div class="treeTools">

                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddNode" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                            CssClass="treeToolsLnk"
                                            Text="" onclick="btnAddNode_Click"><img src="Images/refresh.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
```

and this is my bindtreeview Method

```
#region bindTreeView
private void bindTreeView()
{


    CategoryTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
    using (mydbEntities context = new mydbEntities())
    {


        var parents = context.Categories.Where(a => a.CategoryParentId_FK == null).OrderBy(a => a.Name);

        if (parents.Any())
        {
            foreach (var p in parents)
            {
                TreeNode root = new TreeNode(p.Name, p.Id.ToString());
                root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
                CreateNode(root);
                CategoryTreeView.Nodes.Add(root);
            }
        }



    }


}
void CreateNode(TreeNode node)
{
    using (mydbEntities context = new mydbEntities())
    {
        int p = Int32.Parse(node.Value.ToString());
        var childrens = context.Categories.Where(a => a.CategoryParentId_FK == p).OrderBy(a => a.Name);
        if (childrens.Any())
        {
            foreach (var c in childrens)
            {
                TreeNode tnode = new TreeNode(c.Name, c.Id.ToString());
                tnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
                node.ChildNodes.Add(tnode);
                CreateNode(tnode);

            }
        }

    }


}

#endregion
```

Comment: please show your markup(.aspx) code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to fetch values for the selected node.
The way to do this is to use [SelectedNodeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednodechanged.aspx).

```
<asp:TreeView id="CategoryTreeView"
            Font-Names= "Arial"
            ForeColor="Blue"
            SelectedNodeStyle-ForeColor="Green"
            SelectedNodeStyle-VerticalPadding="0"
            OnSelectedNodeChanged="Select_Change"   
            runat="server">
```

cs:

```
void Select_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     string selectedNodeValue = CategoryTreeView.SelectedNode.Value;
     using (mydbEntities context = new mydbEntities())
        {
            int id = Int32.Parse(selectedNodeValue);
            Category obj = new Category();
            obj.Name = "bla bla";
            obj.CategoryParentId_FK = id;
            context.Categories.AddObject(obj);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

    bindTreeView();

}
```

Comment: I do not think it's true that I write this code in select change